# Accelerate the process of entering the project

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

When a new employee is hired they are attached to an experienced employee that will be helping them at the beginning. This is usually done to

> **Accelerate** the process of entering the project.

Does this phrase sound OK for a native speaker? I'm mostly unsure about using the verb "accelerate" here.

Comment: The situation you're talking about is called *work shadowing*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jan that I'd rather use "to speed up", but this [Google Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speed+up+the+process%2Caccelerate+the+process&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspeed%20up%20the%20process%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccelerate%20the%20process%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cspeed%20up%20the%20process%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccelerate%20the%20process%3B%2Cc0) shows "accelerate" is often used as well. A good part of the 20th century both options were equally used:

[image]